# Residue calculus sinx

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

[image]

Just one quick question: How do you get the $ze^{iaz}$? The formula should be $sinz=(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$.

What's more, why is the other pole $(z+2i)$ not included? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you ended with an incomplete sentence?

Comment: Sorry about that. There was a connection problem. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Euler's formula says

$$e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$$

Thus, if we take only the imaginary part of this integral, we get $\sin \theta$.

Additionally, the singularity at $z=-2i$ is not taken into consideration probably because the author decided to take a contour in the upper half plane.

Comment: Why do we only take the imaginary part of this integral? And can $(z+2i)$ be factored out? Thanks!

Comment: Simply to get rid of the trigonometric function. Also, I apologize; but I made a mistake, it is not removable. However, I'm not sure what you mean by "a singularity at $z+2i$"

Comment: When can we do that to get rid of the trigonometric function? And I meant that since $(z+2i)$ is also a pole, why do we not include its residue?

Comment: @J.doe see my edit.

Comment: Okay. Just a quick question, how to solve for $2+sin2\theta$?

Comment: @J.doe What does it mean to "solve" for an expression?

Comment: Like what are the roots for it?

Comment: It has no roots; $2+sin \theta$ would map to $[1,3]$

Comment: I meant generally speaking, not in this problem. Thanks.